# Any other reason why we use if-let rather than if in Rust?

Tags: if-statement, rust, control-flow

I don't see the reason why we use `if let` and just usual `if`.
In Rust book, chapter 6.3, the sample code is below:

```
let some_u8_value = Some(0u8);
if let Some(3) = some_u8_value {
    println!("three");
}
```

The code above is same with:

```
let some_u8_value = Some(0u8);
if Some(3) == some_u8_value {
    println!("three");
}
```

Any other reason on why we would use `if let` or what is it specifically for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An if let expression is semantically similar to an if expression but
>   in place of a condition expression it expects the keyword let followed
>   by a pattern, an = and a scrutinee expression. If the value of the
>   scrutinee matches the pattern, the corresponding block will execute.
>   Otherwise, flow proceeds to the following else block if it exists.
>   Like if expressions, if let expressions have a value determined by the
>   block that is evaluated.

[Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/expressions/if-expr.html)

`if let` can be used to match any enum value:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz,
    Qux(u32)
}

fn main() {
    // Create example variables
    let a = Foo::Bar;
    let b = Foo::Baz;
    let c = Foo::Qux(100);

    // Variable a matches Foo::Bar
    if let Foo::Bar = a {
        println!("a is foobar");
    }

    // Variable b does not match Foo::Bar
    // So this will print nothing
    if let Foo::Bar = b {
        println!("b is foobar");
    }

    // Variable c matches Foo::Qux which has a value
    // Similar to Some() in the previous example
    if let Foo::Qux(value) = c {
        println!("c is {}", value);
    }

    // Binding also works with `if let`
    if let Foo::Qux(value @ 100) = c {
        println!("c is one hundred");
    }
}
```

Comment: very detailed. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Another reason is if you wish to *use* the pattern bindings. For example consider an enum:

```rust
enum Choices {
  A,
  B,
  C(i32),
}
```

If you wish to implement specific logic for the `C` variant of `Choices`, you can use the if-let expression:

```rust
let choices: Choices = ...;

if let Choices::C(value) = choices {
    println!("{}", value * 2);
}
```