# Why is the let keyword in if-let?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I am learning Rust by the rustbook at the moment and so far i had no problems but if-let makes no sense to me. I think i kinda get what it does but the syntax seems not logical for me and this hinders me to use it.

This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692380/main-difference-between-if-and-if-let-in-rust) explains the differences betwenn if an if-let  but i read the answers and i still cant grasp it.
I dont understand why this syntax was chosen.

The accepted answer from the question i linked has some examples:

```
if let Foo::Bar = a {
    println!("a is foobar");
}
```

My first thought was that let is used because we kinda declare a temporary variable and assign `a` to it and if thats possible the if-block is executed. That would make sense to me.
But then i read the next two examples:

```
if let Foo::Qux(value) = c {
    println!("c is {}", value);
} 
if let Foo::Qux(value @ 100) = c {
    println!("c is one hundred");
}
```

The terms `let Foo::Qux(value)` and `let Foo::Qux(value @ 100)` seem wrong to me. to my understanding i cant declare a variable like this.

What is happening here?

I know about pattern matching but the let keyword makes me feel that there is something i dont get.

Am i right that `let mypattern = myvariable` is basicaly `fn rusts_patternmatching(mypattern, myvariable) ->bool` and the syntax is just confusing for me? Why was the let keyword chosen then?

---

To the comments:
To my understanding it is basicaly the same as pattern matching against one arm. But the let keyword seems so wrong for me to express that, that i feel that i am fundamently wrong about the concept in my head. To me "let" is used to declare a variable in rust. Why was it chosen here for something completly different?

Comment: did you read about pattern matching before ? match ?

Comment: yes but i dont get why we have a let in there. Why the syntax was chosen. the let confuses me and i want to understand why it makes for a patternmatching syntax to have it in there.

Comment: Please check the syntax of `if` and `if let` and their possible combination from the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/if-expr.html). Additional `let` keyword determines that the programmer is trying to destruct the object or just doing a logical check.

Comment: @ÖmerErden can you ellaborate on the use of the let keyword?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking with "why"? Are you wondering specifically why the ``let`` keyword is used here and not another *word*? Are you wondering whether the ``let`` in ``if let`` and a bare ``let`` are the same? Are you aware that both ``let`` and ``if let`` fundamentally work on [Patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes i am asking why let and not another word (but only if this let and the let is use when i declare a variable have different meaning). Yes i am wondering if the let in if let and let are the same. No i am not aware that a bare let has to do with Patterns.

Comment: `if let` means 'if pattern matches, open new scope and bind the matched value in that scope'.

Comment: @goodsnek I am not sure why the `let` keyword has chosen but I doubt it can be considered as wrong. Please check the code(2nd block in Motivation section)from the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0160-if-let.md). It consists by 2 operation. Checks the pattern then assigns it to a variable. For Rust there is 2 keyword that do this job, first one is `if` and the latter one is `let`.

Comment: I would agree this was the most kooky syntax for me learning Rust. It's quite 'unreadable' in my view. I still have to concentrate to think about it each time. I am not a fan of "if let". But oh well, this ship has sailed. We'd better get used to it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `let` and `if let` work on a single [Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html); name assignment is a side-effect of matching the pattern. For example, `let (a, b) = (1, 2)` matches `(1, 2)` to the pattern `(a, b)`.

The difference is that `let` is a *required* ("irrefutable") match, whereas `if let` is a *possible* ("refutable") match. The possibility of not matching the pattern is expressed by `if`.

```rust
fn main() {
    // don't do this at home
    if let (a, b) = (1, 2) {
        println!("{} {}", a, b);
    };
}
```

See also [RFC 160: `if let`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0160-if-let.md) for the rationale of creating `if let` as a conditional (`if`) pattern match (`let`) and background.

Comment: I finally "got" it with the formal specification: `if let PAT = EXPR { BODY }`. Does the EXPR match the PAT? if so then us the bindings in the PAT to do BODY.